# While opening links in reverse order in new tabs, I want to exclude "sports" and "IR" links

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to open links from contents from bottom to top in new tab:

```
driver.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sports_video_game");
        WebElement contents = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='toc']"));
        List<WebElement> links = contents.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
        String clickonlinkTab=Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.ENTER);
         for(int i = links.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
links.get(i).sendKeys(clickonlinkTab);
links.findElement(By.partialLinkText("sports")).notclick();
links.findElement(By.partialLinkText("IR")).notclick();
}
```

I want Selenium to skip links which has "sports" and "IR" any where on it.

Comment: OK, and what exactly the problem here?

Comment: notclick(); is not a proper method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As "notclick" is not a valid method, the simplest solution is to check if the link text contains "Sports" or "IR" before performing the click action. E.g:

```
for (int i = links.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (!(links.get(i).getText().toLowerCase().contains("sports")
        || links.get(i).getText().toLowerCase().contains("ir"))) {
        links.get(i).sendKeys(clickonlinkTab);
    }
}
```

[Here](https://mx1.maxtaf.com/cases/c778fdb2-86c4-4ed3-8b3c-81cb7282b891?projectId=bugtestproject2) is a link to a runnable test case where you can see the results, including printing to verify that it works. If you want to edit, making an account can be done for free via the edit button.

Comment: Is it possible to store "sports" and "ir" into string[] and then call that string[] into "if" loop?

Comment: Can't think of a way to make that work without just pulling the values out of the string array, which is just more coding.